# .NET Use BouncyCastle to read ECC Certificate from Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I have generate some ECC Certificate using OpenSSL. I can see these certificates in windows store.

What I want to do is to load an ECC certificate, get its private key, public key to use in other encryption method, like:

```
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection x509Certificate2Collection = 
        store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "008B2D89B2A75EE891", false);

    X509Certificate2 cert= x509Certificate2Collection[0];
    (use Bouncy Castle to read it here)
```

I also try with:

```
    var asymmetricCipherKeyPair = 
        DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(x509Certificate2.PrivateKey);
```

But this give an Exception:

```
    {"The certificate key algorithm is not supported."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}
```

Comment: Can you please provide full stacktrace? What curve did you use?